# Consulta de tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Tengo un pequeño problema con una consulta de los registros de una tabla relacionada.
El caso va así:
Tengo una tabla de 'trabajadores' la cual está relacionada a una tabla de 'turnos de trabajo' a través de un campo de la tabla 'trabajadores', y quisiera poder saber el nombre y los demás datos de la tabla 'turnos de trabajo' al momento de traerme todos los datos de la tabla ' trabajadores'. Es decir, poder tener todos los datos de casda trabajador, además del turno de trabajo, y no sólo tener el ID del turno que se guarda en la tabla trabajadores.

Consulta de la tabla trabajadores a mejorar para poder realizar la consulta relacionada:

```
public function index(WorkTurns $workturn){

    $workers = Workers::all();
    return view('hotel::workers.index', compact('workers'));

}
```

Tabla de trabajadores

```
class Workers extends ModelTenant
{
protected $table = 'workers';

protected $fillable = [

    'name',
    'dni',
    'phone_number',
    'email',
    'workturn_id'

];

public $timestamps = false;

public function workturn(): BelongsTo{

    return $this -> belongsTo(WorkTurns::class, 'workturn_id') -> select('id', 'turn');

}

}
```

Tabla de turnos:

```
class WorkTurns extends ModelTenant
{
protected $table = 'workturns';

protected $fillable = [

    'turn',
    'start',
    'end'

];

public $timestamps = false;

public function workers(): HasMany{

    return $this -> hasMany(Workers::class);

}

}
```

Lo que quiero es obtener los datos del trabajador y, a la vez, saber el nombre del turno al cual pertenece. Por ejemplo:
Trabajador: Brayan Rodríguez, DNI: xxxxxxx, Turno: Vespertino (en lugar del id del turno)

Actualización:
Intenté de la siguiente manera y sigue sin funcionar:

```
public function index(WorkTurns $workturn){

    $workers = Workers::with('workturn') -> get();

    return view('hotel::workers.index', compact('workers'));

}
```

Comment: Hacen falta datos, por ejemplo el tipo de relación entre las tablas, además un ejemplo de la salida que esperas ayudaría, así como saber que has intentado al momento

Comment: Ya está más completa la información

Comment: Ya que tienes las relaciones definidas en los modelos entonces con [**eager loading**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) es muy simple de lograr lo que buscas

Comment: Voy a revisar ese artículo a ver

Comment: @BetaM, estoy intentando con el artículo que nombraste, pero sigo sin recibir más allá del id del turno. Aún no se ejecuta la consulta a la tabla de turnos.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega como intentaste tu consulta, por cierto no es un artículo, es la documentación oficial de Laravel

Comment: Listo, ya está editada

Comment: Se puede deber a que tus modelos no siguen las convenciones esperadas por Eloquent, te recomiendo leas a detalle [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) [y aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Las relaciones que muestras no siguen las convenciones de Laravel. Verifica en la documentación. [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). Seguido de ello prueba utilizando la carga de tus datos con **eager loading** como te lo sugieren